# How can I call a reflected Func<T, T> property using Expression Trees

Tags: c#, linq-expressions

I have a generic class with a lambda property defined as such:

```
public class Transformation<TProperty> : TransformationBase
{
    public Func<TProperty, TProperty> Transform { get; private set; }
    ...
```

I'm trying to compile an Action that can call this Transform property (on a property of Foo). I don't know TProperty at compile-time. I've started with this:

```
    private static Action<Foo> Compile(Transformation transformation)
    {
        var fooParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Foo));
        var changePropertyValue = Expression.Constant(transformation);
        var transformProperty = Expression.Property(changePropertyValue, "Transform");
        var transfromCall = Expression.Call(transformProperty, ?
    }
```

How can I call/execute the transformProperty?

EDIT: Foo (which is known a compile time) has an untyped property Value which needs to be transformed using the Transform property of the Transformation:

```
    public class Foo {
         public object Value { get; set; }
    }
```

So, hand-written as an example where TProperty is string it would be:

```
    Foo foo = ... // coming from an external source
    Transformation<string> tranformation = ... // coming from an external source
    foo.Value = transformation.Transform((string)foo.Value);
```

Except that I don't know the exact type of the Transformation as it is defined in an external assembly. So, instead of string it could be int or something else. That's why I want to use Expression Trees to compile an Action for a given transformation, such that I can call:

```
    Foo foo = ... // coming from an external source
    TransformationBase transformation = ... // coming from an external source
    Action<Foo> transform = Compile(transformation);
    transform(foo); // should transform foo.Value using the Transform property of 'transformation'
```

Note: I made Transformation inherit from TransformationBase to clarify this discussion.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. What's the relation between `Foo` and `TProperty`? What's the relation between `Transformation` and `Transformation<TProperty>`? Is the `Compile` method on the `Transformation<TProperty>` class? Is using expression trees a requirement or just how you're attempting to do it?

Comment: What are you trying to do will be much easier to understand if you provide very small example of code - for example, what should you `Action` do in fact.

Comment: @BenAaronson: `Compile` is outside of `Transformation<T>` and `Foo`. I hope my further description clarifies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems relate more to the lack of typing around your problem. `Foo.Value` is loosely typed, but your transform functions are strongly typed. Expression Trees are also strongly typed. Using them doesn't allow you to magically call code in a loosely typed manner.

The solution is either a lot of reflection, or some easy dynamic:

EDIT: I added CompileUntyped which uses ExpressionTrees.I also added CompileReflection, which uses Reflection without ExpressionTrees. I would recommend the one that uses dynamic. It is by far the easiest to read, hence the easiest to maintain.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var testTransform = new Transformation<string>
            {
                Transform = s => s.ToUpper()
            };
        var a = Compile(testTransform);
        var foo = new Foo
            {
                Value = "test"
            };

        a(foo);

        //foo.Value is now TEST
    }

    public static Action<Foo> CompileReflection(TransformationBase transformation)
    {
        var f = transformation
            .GetType()
            .GetProperty("Transform")
            .GetGetMethod()
            .Invoke(transformation, null) as Delegate;

        return foo => foo.Value = f.DynamicInvoke(foo.Value);

    }

    public static Action<Foo> Compile(TransformationBase transformation)
    {
        return new Action<Foo>(f =>
            {
                dynamic d = f.Value;
                dynamic t = transformation;
                f.Value = t.Transform(d);
            });
    }

    public static Action<Foo> CompileUntyped(TransformationBase transformation)
    {
        var transformType = transformation.GetType();
        var genericType = transformType.GetGenericArguments().First();

        var fooParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Foo), "f");

        var valueGetter = typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Value").GetGetMethod();
        var valueSetter = typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Value").GetSetMethod();
        var transformFuncMember = transformType.GetProperty("Transform").GetGetMethod();

        //Equivalent to f => f.Value = transformation.Transform((T)f.Value)
        //Where T is the generic type parameter of the Transformation, and f is of type Foo
        var expression = Expression.Lambda<Action<Foo>>(
            Expression.Call(
                fooParam,
                valueSetter,
                Expression.Invoke(
                    Expression.Property(
                        Expression.Constant(transformation, transformType), 
                        transformFuncMember
                    ),
                    Expression.Convert(
                        Expression.Property(fooParam, valueGetter),
                        genericType
                    )
                )
            ), fooParam
        );
        return expression.Compile();
    }

}

public class TransformationBase { }

public class Transformation<TProperty> : TransformationBase
{
    public Func<TProperty, TProperty> Transform { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is a possible solution and yes, my problem is a bit odd in respect to typing. But my question is a general one. How can I call a property of type Func<T, T> using Exrpression Trees. And this, nobody answered so far.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what are you trying to do BUT if I understand your intentions - I do not see need for compiling `Expressions`:

```
private static Action<TProperty> Compile<TProperty>(Transformation<TProperty> transformation)
{
    return new Action<TProperty>(p => transformation.Transform(p));
}
```

Comment: Sorry, for being a bit too short in my first shot. It should be clear now that the Action must act on `Foo` and not `TProperty`.

Answer (score 0):

See an example, it should give you what you want.

```
void Main()
{

    var dummyObject = new Dummy { Test = "Hello!" };

    var propertyTransform = Create(dummyObject, "Test");

    propertyTransform(dummyObject);

    Console.WriteLine("Final transformation " + dummyObject.Test);
}

class Dummy {
    public string Test { get; set; }
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Transformation<TProperty>
{
    public Func<TProperty, TProperty> Transform { get; set; }
}

public static Action<TObj> Create<TObj>(TObj myObject, string property){
    var prop = myObject
        .GetType()
        .GetProperty(property);

    var val = prop.GetValue(myObject);

    var transformation = Create((dynamic)val);
    var transform = transformation.Transform;

    return obj => {

        var newValue = transform((dynamic)val);

        prop.SetValue(myObject, newValue);
    };
}

public static Transformation<TProperty> Create<TProperty>(TProperty property){

    var transformation = new Transformation<TProperty>();

    // just a dummy hijacking.
    if(typeof(TProperty)==typeof(string)){

        Func<string, string> test = input => "I am changed man!";

        transformation.Transform = (dynamic)test;
    }

    return transformation;
}
```

Output:

> `Final transformation I am changed man!`

Comment: Sorry, for being a bit too short in my first shot. I've added more to the description so it should be clear that `Foo` is type that is known a compile time where `TProperty` of the `Transformation<TProperty>` is not. So your suggestion does not help.

Comment: @Dejan: `Action<Foo> = (Foo foo) => transformation.Transform((dynamic)(foo.Value))` should work.

Comment: I cannot call `Transform` as it is defined in `Transformation<TProperty>`. I only have a reference to a instance of type `TransformationBase`.

Comment: What about `Action<Foo> = foo => ((dynamic)transformation).Transform((dynamic)(foo.Value))`?